# adding documentation to prototype

Tags: javascript, jsdoc

i've been writing my own helper library for my day to day tinkering, and like to add documentation to each function i create. now the issue i am having is the following:

the way i add documentation to most of my function works and no issue
lets take my (w3schools copied) rng

```
    /**
     * a function for generating an integer between a and b.
     * further documentation...
     * @param {!number} min - this is the lower bound
     * @param {!number} max - this is the higher bound
    */
    function random (min, max){
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) ) + min;
    }
```

this works and gives me the proper instructions in my ide(?) vsc

now the issue is when i try to add it to an existing js object like number
take my function to see if a number is between two other numbers

```
/**
 * a function for checking if n is between but not equals a and b.
 * @param {!number} lower - the lower number 
 * @param {!number} higher - the higher number
*/
Number.prototype.isBetween = function (lower, higher) {
    return (this > lower && this < higher || this > higher && this < lower) ? true : false;
}
```

this does not even give me the suggestion that `myVar.isBetween(a,b)` is a function nor gives it me any documentation

Comment: An easy solution would be to NOT modify the prototype of native objects? You lose optimizations and a lot of other things when you do that.

Comment: it would be nice if i could do it like this so i can just check a variable with `myVar.isBetween(1,10)` if there is a better option where i can do the same i would love to know about it!

Comment: Well the better option would be to just make isBetween a separate function? Then it can have JSDoc.

Comment: Rest assured I fiddled around with some different ways to try to get JSDoc on the prototype but none have worked. Maybe there is a JSDoc directive but IDK.